# Modal verb in the beginning of a sentence

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

I am reading The Lord of the Ring where I found this sentence:
May you have joy of the sight, my good dwarf!

Is it a correct usage of modal verb? I have not found any grammar rule for this case.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is grammatical and current usage in formal contexts, to express a wish or desire.

- May all your dreams come true.
- May the New Year bring you joy and happiness.
- May the peace of Christmas be with you.

Comment: Let the games begin! Would that it be so. Should you ever see such things again. I'm not sure about that first one.

Comment: May your days be merry and bright, and may all your Christmases be white.

Comment: @Centaurus - more examples of sentences beginning with modals. 'let' is usually not considered a modal but it seems to act like one here.

Comment: Thank you. If I changed may in this sentence with another modal verb like would or should, would meaning be the same?

Comment: @dekko No, the meaning wouldn't be the same.   "Should you have any more doubts about it, feel free to contact me" = "If you have any more doubts..."